I'm searching for the original paper from 1924 where Max Born first proposed the term "quantum mechanics."
I'm searching for historical documents pertaining to quantum mechanics because I aim to write a popular essay on the topic for a web magazine. Specifically, I'm seeking free access to Max Born's paper "Über Quantenmechanik," in which he coined the term 'quantum mechanics' exactly a century ago from this year (2024). This paper was published in Zeitschrift für Physik, December 1924, within Volume 26, pages 379–395. Could you assist me in locating it online?

There is an English translation of this paper in the book: Van der Waerden, Sources of quantum mechanics, north Holland, 1967. And the book is available online.

I found this English translation taken from van der Waerden's book: http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/SQM289.pdf;
the layout seems a bit strange to me, but it's better than nothing.

Thank you for your suggestion. However, the paper you mentioned is from a year later than what I'm seeking. It wasn't published in a German scientific journal in December 1924. If online access for free isn't feasible, I intend to request a photocopy by mail from a university library that purportedly possesses back issues from that era. Nonetheless, it would be more convenient if it were accessible online at no cost.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01327341 , but its not free.

The fault is mine, I didn't think that German physicists had such poor imagination with titles, so I picked the wrong chapter (13 instead of 7); anyway, if you're interested in the English translation, here is the link: https://books.google.it/books?id=s_XovCVfqNcC&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q&f=false (at the moment, you can read everything). If you want the original German instead, there is an open source, but you need to reside in the USA (or use a VPN, e. g. Opera): https://hdl.handle.net/2027/inu.30000089907145?urlappend=%3Bseq=389

Thank you for sending the link. It's exactly what I've been looking for! On the other hand, I currently reside in Japan, which makes it difficult for me to access the original German text you shared with me.

While there are numerous books on the history of quantum theory, many studies that were later proven incorrect are often left out from these textbooks. This omission makes it challenging to track the development of quantum theory, with its many trials and errors. That's why I make an effort to read original papers from each era whenever possible. I'm continually struck by how many of the studies later deemed incorrect still played very crucial roles in guiding subsequent, correct research.

@AlexandreEremenko It's quite incomprehensible that mr. Van der Waerden did not translate German quotes in his book! Must be one of those quantum puzzles.

Here is some material on Born's "quantum mechanics": https://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft4t1nb2gv&chunk.id=d0e14702&toc.depth=100&toc.id=d0e14152&brand=ucpress

Moreover, see the Section 10.3 in the excellent book: "Quantum Concepts in Physics: An Alternative Approach to the Understanding of Quantum Mechanics"

This article is freely available on Archive.org. You may need to create a free account to read the volume, but there is no need to borrow the book, like there is for many of the volumes on Archive. Of course, the article is in German.
Apparently this book was digitized by Google and is also available on the google books site, but I have been unable to find a version that allows a free view.

Thanks! I tried looking for it on the Internet Archive a few days ago but couldn't find it at that time. How were you able to locate it? I'm curious to know if you're open to sharing.
This paper came close to discussing the concept later introduced by Heisenberg in 1925, known as "matrix mechanics". It's not frequently referenced in quantum mechanics textbooks, but I think it holds significance in the evolution of quantum mechanics.

@enjin2000 I think it was simply a search for the journal name with "vol 26" after it. I just tried to recreate that search using "volume 26" and it doesn't work, so simply random chance that I used vol instead of volume.

How absolutely simple, Sherlock. THX!
